# Close WPF window after animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm using an animation to cause a window to fade out of focus, then close.

However, the close event occurs immediately after the animation.

What is the simplest way to make the window close after the animation?

In the following code, MainWindow is the second window that is being opened. This method is called when a button is clicked in the first window.

```
private void CloseMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
    win.Show();
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = 1.0,
        To = 0.0,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    };
    this.BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, animation);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " fade out of the focus"? Slowly getting transparent until complete disappearance?

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino yes you are right. Sorry, that wasn't clear.

Comment: Just to make sure if I understand. Do the animation run completely before the `this.Close();` instruction is called?

Comment: As it is now, the first window (that the animation is called on) closes immediately, with no animation, and the second window shows. If I comment out `this.Close()` the second window shows and the animation occurs on the first window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this will happen. The animation is async in nature and the close function will execute directly after starting the animation.

The best way is to call the close function on the Completed event of the animation. In this case you write:

```
/////
 {
 DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
        // init you animation
 anim.Completed += anim_Completed;
  }  
  ////
    void anim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I accepted Omar's answer, but for purposes of learning also wanted to point out that if a [Storyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used, the `Completed` event can be used to call a method to close a window, after the animation in the storyboard has occurred. Coupled with a `Button.Click` method, this can also achieve the desired effect:

```
<Button Foreground="Red" ToolTip="Close this window." Click="ShowMainWin">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="EntireWindow"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        From="1.0" To="0.0"
                        Duration="0:0:0.5"
                        Completed="CloseMethod"></DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    Close Window</Button>
```

And, in the code, I define `"ShowMainWin"` and `"CloseMethod"`.

`"ShowMainWin"` happens when the button is clicked, causing the second window to open immediately. The animation in the `Storyboard` runs, causing the first window to fade away. Once the animation is complete, `"CloseMethod"` is called, causing the first window to close:

```
private void ShowMainWin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
    win.Show();
}

public void CloseMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```